# aws efs filesystem is not listing with describe-file-systems

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

EFS file system is created properly though `aws console` but when I try to list the same through command prompt, getting below errors.

```
aws efs describe-file-systems --file-system-id fs-0568723



An error occurred (FileSystemNotFound) when calling the DescribeFileSystems operation: File system 'fs-0568723' does not exist.
```

Could you please suggest me.

Comment: Double check region. Maybe in AWS console you are using different region then for CLI.

Comment: Thank you....that issue is resolved now...but getting below  Warning  FailedMount             53s (x9 over 3m1s)  kubelet, ip-192-171-22-131.ec2.internal  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "awscspv" : kubernetes.io/csi: attacher.MountDevice failed to create newCsiDriverClient: driver name efs.csi.aws.com not found in the list of registered CSI drivers ..could you please suggest

Comment: thanks ..i got the answer for this....

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using **different region** in AWS console than that use for AWS CLI.

The solution was to use correct region.